# Candidate Excel Functions for GPU acceleration

Tags: excel, opencl, gpu

I'm currently looking into writing an OpenCL Excel plugin.  This would expose a set of functions that offer calculations to be performed on the GPU from Excel.  As a proof of concept I've written an Array-sum kernel and exposed this successfully.  It works well, having no noticeable latency introduced (the entire array sum for 5k elements takes about 7ms start to finish).

My question is, what other candidate functions would you think would be useful in this context.  I've got some ideas for Prefix Sum and Mersenne Prime kernels.

Al

Comment: It's scary to think that there are Excel spreadsheets out there large enough to actually benefit from GPU acceleration...

Comment: though scary as that is, I am one of the people spawning them.... 
(I say spawn as they are evil and hang mere mortal machines)

Comment: I prefer a web page with table inputs and serverside opencl compute. Much easier to do, works everywhere.